# Using cloudpebble.net for chalk javascript app

Tags: pebble-sdk

I am using the cloudpebble.net to write my app. The app is working fine in the emulator. But when i try to put it in my watch, the pebble phone application show that my app don't support my watch.
After some search in the internet it's seem that my app is not compiled for my watch (the pebble round, using chalk sdk). On the webide, i can't compile my applifaction for chalck, (grey button). Am i missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! Pebble updated CloudPebble to support Chalk apps in Pebble.js. As of 5/17/2016 there are still some UI bugs to work out, but the emulator works.

You can go into Settings in one of your projects and enable *Build Chalk* to target Chalk platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "SETTINGS" when your project is opened, there are checkboxes for every platform and you can choose what platform it should be built for.  Make sure "BUILD CHALK" is checked.  Then go to "COMPILATION" and click "RUN BUILD".  You should now be able to run it in the chalk emulator as well as install it to your watch.

If you cannot see CHALK in the list, it's because your project is built upon Pebble.js and that is not yet supported as of 2016-01-12.

If you cannot see any platforms to select, you need to switch to SDK 3.0 and reload the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, on this interface i can only check for aplite or basalt.
Maybe i missed something ?

Comment: Well if you are really currently on http://cloudpebble.net then it means it shows each one of us different thing. I would suggesting also checking for the SDK version, you might be using version 2. Don't forget to reload the page after changing the SDK version. I currently cannot check whether that's it because the server is not accessible for me right now. Let me know if thta was the case so I can update the answer so others can find the right solution as well.

Comment: @Elfangor I updated the answer, could you check that it's the case for you as well?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use the Pebble.js, which like you say is not supported for Chalk. I asked the support and they say that it will come but they don't have a date yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got a answer from the pebble developper, right now pebble.js doesn't support the chalk framework.

Time to use C !